# UninstallHandler not working

Tags: apex, 2gp, uninstall

Want to have my 2GP do a little cleanup when it is removed. One of the post-install steps clones a template Permission Set and assigns users to the clone. When my 2GP is uninstalled, I am trying to reverse the process but it doesn't seem to be working (but it's also not throwing errors)...

```
public without sharing class MyUninstallClass implements UninstallHandler {
  public void onUninstall(UninstallContext context) {
    // Query for the cloned Permission Set
    PermissionSet ps = [SELECT Id FROM PermissionSet WHERE Name = :Utility.ORG_PERMISSIONSET_NAME LIMIT 1];
    if (ps == null) {
      return;
    }

    List<PermissionSetAssignment> psaList = [
      SELECT Id
      FROM PermissionSetAssignment
      WHERE PermissionSetId = :ps.Id
    ];

    if (!psaList.isEmpty()) {
      try {
        // Delete the PermissionSetAssignment records
        delete psaList;
        System.debug('User assignments successfully removed from the Permission Set');
      } catch (DmlException e) {
        System.debug('An error occurred while removing user assignments: ' + e.getMessage());
      }
    } else {
      System.debug('No user assignments found for the specified Permission Set');
    }

    if (Schema.sObjectType.PermissionSet.isDeletable()) {
      delete ps;
    }
  }
}
```

I've used some similar anonymous Apex to do cleanup. Not sure why this isn't working.

Any thoughts?